# FileSystemWatcher Changed Event not being raised

Tags: .net, vb.net, filesystemwatcher

I'm working on a Windows Service that watches a few folders for changes, creations, and deletions.  It all works well with the exception of one watcher that watches a single file (XML File with Configuration Settings) for minor changes.

I tried taking the Windows Service code and putting it into a simple windows application with start/stop buttons for the filesystem watchers and stepped through it.  It never detects the file change of the XML config file.  The changes are indeed occurring and the "Date Modified" of the file is updating.

```
XmlEventReferences = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()
XmlEventReferences.Path = "C:\XmlReferences\"
XmlEventReferences.Filter = "*.xml"
XmlEventReferences.NotifyFilter = IO.NotifyFilters.FileName
AddHandler XmlEventReferences.Changed, AddressOf ReloadEventReferences
AddHandler XmlEventReferences.Created, AddressOf ReloadEventReferences
AddHandler XmlEventReferences., AddressOf ReloadEventReferences
XmlEventReferences.EnableRaisingEvents = True
```

That was some of the code and this is a sample of the XML File:

```
<EventReference>
    <ER_EL_NUMBER>1</ER_EL_NUMBER>
    <ER_SEND_TO_DATABASE>true</ER_SEND_TO_DATABASE>
    <ER_ACTIVATE_ALARM>true</ER_ACTIVATE_ALARM>
    <ER_DESCRIPTION />
</EventReference>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the problem is the value of `NotifyFilter`. You've actually only told the `FileSystemWatcher` to look for file name changes. To get it to raise the `Changed` event for file modifications too, you'll want to specify the `LastWrite` flag as well.

i.e. The appropiate line of code should be changed to:

```
XmlEventReferences.NotifyFilter = IO.NotifyFilters.FileName |
    IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
```

See the [`NotifyFilters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx) page on MSDN for more info.

Note: As Joshua Belden points out, you don't even need to set the `NotifyFilter` property at all because as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx) states: "The default is the bitwise OR combination of LastWrite, FileName, and DirectoryName." However, I would argue that it's always best to be explicit in such cases - it then makes it perfectly obvious as to what the `FileSystemWatcher` is and is *not* watching.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `.NotifyFilter` to something like `LastWrite` to pick up changes i believe.

MSDN link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This code seemed to work for me, picked up an edit to a test.xml file. Are

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim XmlEventReferences = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()
    XmlEventReferences.Path = "C:\"
    XmlEventReferences.Filter = "*.xml"
    XmlEventReferences.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    AddHandler XmlEventReferences.Changed, AddressOf Watch
End Sub

Private Sub Watch(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    Dim s As String = e.FullPath
End Sub
```

Dump the notify filter all together.

Comment: From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx): "The default is the bitwise OR combination of LastWrite, FileName, and DirectoryName." So yeah, you don't need the line specifying NotifyFilter, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit about what you are watchin for. (I would include it anyway for this reason.)